# display console result on java GUI for each class (java newbie programmer)

Tags: java

guys..i has a simple question.

is it possible to display each class console result on java GUI ?

Each class has different console results..

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
```

import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class SimpleWebCrawler {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    try {
        URL my_url = new URL("http://theworldaccordingtothisgirl.blogspot.com/");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                my_url.openStream()));
        String strTemp = "";
        while (null != (strTemp = br.readLine())) {
            System.out.println(strTemp);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("\n");

    Validate.isTrue(args.length == 0, "usage: supply url to crawl");
    String url = "http://theworldaccordingtothisgirl.blogspot.com/";
    print("Fetching %s...", url);

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

    System.out.println("\n");

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("abc.txt"));

    for (Element link : links) {
        print("  %s  ", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));

        bw.write(link.attr("abs:href"));
        bw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();

}

private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
    System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
}

private static String trim(String s, int width) {
    if (s.length() > width)
        return s.substring(0, width - 1) + ".";
    else
        return s;

}
```

}

Example output :

Fetching http://theworldaccordingtothisgirl.blogspot.com/...

http://theworldaccordingtothisgirl.blogspot.com/2011/03/in-time-like-this.html
  https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-yz2ql0o45Aw/TYBNhyFVpMI/AAAAAAAAAGU/OrPZrBjwWi8/s1600/Malaysian-Newspaper-Apologises-For-Tsunami-Cartoon.jpg
  http://ireport.cnn.com/docs/DOC-571892
  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-nXOxDT4ZyWA/TX-HaKoHE3I/AAAAAAAAAGQ/xwXJ-8hNt1M/s1600/ScrnShotsDesktop-1213678160_large.png
  http://theworldaccordingtothisgirl.blogspot.com/2011/03/in-time-like-this.html#comments
  http://www.blogger.com/share-post.g?blogID=3284083343891767749&postID=785884436807581777&target=email
  http://www.blogger.com/share-post.g?blogID=3284083343891767749&postID=785884436807581777&target=blog
  http://www.blogger.com/share-post.g?blogID=3284083343891767749&postID=785884436807581777&target=twitter
  http://www.blogger.com/share-post.g?blogID=3284083343891767749&postID=785884436807581777&target=facebook
  http://www.blogger.com/share-post.g?blogID=3284083343891767749&postID=785884436807581777&target=buzz

Comment: What is a console result? An example of what you want to do would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to separate the standard output (`System.out.println`) based on which class it comes from, the answer is, no, (not easily at least).

I suggest you let each class that wants to do output get a `PrintWriter` as argument to the constructor, then use that `PrintWriter` instead of the `System.out` print writer.